# Web Application as iphone native app

Tags: iphone, web

As facebook is a web application, in which we post comments, post snaps, chat etc. There is also an also facebook available as iOS native app and mobile app. We have similar kind of web application like facebook, we want to make a native application of that web application.

Is there any solution to this?

Please reply this

Comment: Have a look through the full list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development#Platform_development_environment

Answer (score 1):

Try Titanium Appcelator to create iOS application from your web applications.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is for you to create web-services for your web application and then create an app that uses/consumes those.

Answer (score 0):

Web-app's can NEVER be native!

Unless you will 'convert' it into a 'native-language'-application.

If Titanium Appcelator will do this thing for you, it will be a nice solution to make a 'native web application'!

Otherwise, you need to use your web skills to create a XML or JSON file, with a language like PHP or ASP/ASP.net. You will need to get the content of the XML/JSON file from a database or another XML/JSON file which got comments, pictures, etc. in it. You will need to parse it with a native language (C++/C for iOS, Visual Basic for WP and Java for Android) and make a good-looking application using the native language. Your application is now a native application which needs the web to work.

Greetings, Amanush!

---

EDIT: You can make a 'webbrowser' app as well, which will always browse to your online application. It will be a slow solution.